# Python Simple Statistics

Tags: python

Needing a little help finishing this! I was able to get the final output of **1050.60** but struggling on the rest.
Given 3 floating-point numbers. Use a string formatting expression with conversion specifiers to output their average and their product as integers, then as floating-point numbers.

Output each floating-point value with two digits after the decimal point, which can be achieved as follows:

`print('%0.2f' % your_value)`

**Ex: If the input is:**

```
10.3
20.4
5.0
```

**the output is:**

```
11 1050
11.90 1050.60
```

Here is what I have:

```
num1 = float(input())
num2 = float(input())
num3 = float(input())

average = (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3

your_value = num1 * num2 * num3
print('%0.2f' % your_value)
```

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? Assuming you know the math formula for sum and product, then the rest is just formatting the output. If you need help converting from float to int, you can google "python convert float to int".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
num1 = float(input())
num2 = float(input())
num3 = float(input())
average = (num1+num2+num3) / 3

your_value = num1*num2*num3
print('%0.0f %0.0f %0.2f %0.2f' % (int(average), int(your_value), average, your_value))
# or:
print(f"{int(average)} {int(your_value)} {round(average,2)} {round(your_value,2)}")
```

if I understood your mean, correctly, it is your answer:

1.
you must set display format for all values: %0.2f

2.
use f-string in this format: f"{}" and add your value in {}

3.
int: convert float to integer and round: round up number

Answer (score 0):

```
    #user input values
    num1 = float(input())
    num2 = float(input())
    num3 = float(input())
    
    #product and average of the user's input 
    product = num1 * num2 * num3
    average = (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3
    
    #print them in the following format
    print(f'{product:.0f} {average:.0f}')
    print(f'{product:.2f} {average:.2f}')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code solves your problem in a simple manner:

```py
num1 = float(input())
num2 = float(input())
num3 = float(input())

average = (num1+num2+num3) /3
product = num1*num2*num3

# Print average & product
print('%d %d' % (int(average), int(product)))

# Print average & product (as `float`)
print('%0.2f %0.2f' % (average, product))
```